# Cannot redirect to a route from HttpPost action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to redirect to a route in my action method which has a POST action verb.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/SubmitConfiguration", Name = "SubmitConfigurationRoute")]
public ActionResult SubmitConfiguration([FromBody] JObject ConfigDataObject)
{
    return RedirectToRoutePermanent(routeName: "ConfigRoute");
}
```

This is the action method which has the route I'm trying to route to.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/Config", Name = "ConfigRoute")]

public ActionResult Config()
{
   return View();
}
```

---

It's unable to redirect to that particular route.

Does `HTTP` protocol prohibit redirecting from `POST` methods?

---

Edit: Here's a snapshot from the network tab
[image]

Comment: No, `HTTP` does not prohibit redirecting from `POST`, what do you mean by "It's unable to redirect to that particular route"?

Comment: I am not able to redirect to that particular action method `Config` via this statement: `return RedirectToRoutePermanent(routeName: "ConfigRoute");`

Comment: Is it an exception? What is the response?

Comment: No exception thrown, it simply doesn't redirect to that route.

Comment: @AlexSikilinda debugging stops  at `return RedirectToRoutePermanent(routeName: "ConfigRoute");`

Comment: Can you provide the response of the first action method? You can check it in `Network` tab in the chrome developer tools.

Comment: @AlexSikilinda updated the question

Comment: Well, it shows that `\Config` route is invoked, and the previous `\SubmitConfiguration` returns 301, which is the redirect you are looking for.

Comment: but even if its invoked, its not invoking the view

Comment: If you can see that you are getting a 200 on `Config` (which you can), then everything is working. For Chrome to show a 200, that means ASP.NET Core did everything it needed to do (including rendering the view) and sent the response successfully to the client. Now if the view is *blank* or otherwise doesn't have the content you think it should. That means that there's something wrong with the view or the view you think should be coming is not. However, in either case, it's an issue with your code, and one we don't have any visibility into currently.